# Facebook Video Page Post with Call to Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I want to post a video to facebook with call to action button but it seems the video was successfully posted on facebook page but call to action button was ignored. Anyone has any idea what could the problem please?

```
curl -F 'name=My Video' \
-F 'description=This is my first video' \
-F 'source=@myvideo.mp4' \
-F 'published=1' \
-F 'call_to_action={"type":"LEARN_MORE","value":{"link":"<LINK>","link_format":"VIDEO_LPP"}}' \
-F 'access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>' https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.8/<PAGE_ID>/videos
```